# C++ Easiest most efficient way to move a single element to a new position within a vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Sorry for my potential nOOb'ness but have been trying to get this for hours and cant seem to find an elegant solution for c++ 98.

My question is, say i have a vector of strings { a,b,c,d,e,f } and i want to move 'e' to the 2nd element how would i do so? Obviously the expected output would now print out { a,e,b,c,d,f }

Ideally looking for a single operation that lets me do this just for efficiency reasons but would love to hear some suggestions on how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need to do this kind of thing a lot then `std::vector` was probably not the best choice for a container.

Comment: Do not use vectors. Use std::list instead - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Comment: Use `erase` and `insert`.

Comment: The term "single operation" is awfully loose. A single API call? See [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate). A constant-time insertion? A different matter entirely.

Comment: You probably want an std::list.

Comment: Straustrup suggests avoiding std::list https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo Quite an interesting lecture.

Comment: @Jarod42: that's not efficient--see my answer for why.

Comment: Before taking anyone's advice to switch to `std::list`, profile your code. I think you'll find `std::vector` outperforms `std::list` in most use cases, even when you have operations which result in a higher complexity due to the way `std::vector` stores its data.

Comment: I concur with @BenjaminLindley on this. Definitely profile. You may be surprised how quickly that rotate is done if the sequence is sufficiently small. The benefits in *other* places of your code that may reap rewards from linear scans coupled with the rarity of this operation may warrant keeping a vector+rotate algorithm.

Comment: Just looking at the requested operation and ignoring the (IMHO not so) "obvious" result, you could just swap the element with the one at the target position. The only faster way I could imagine is to avoid the movement completely, like e.g. setting an offset that is added to every index to target the 'e' with index 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** As noted in the comments, the below code actually mimics `std::rotate`, which is of course preferred above my hand-rolled code in all cases.

---

You can accomplish this with K swaps where K is the distance between the elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string v = "abcdef"; // use string here so output is trivial

  string::size_type insert_index = 1; // at the location of 'b'
  string::size_type move_index = 4; // at the location of 'e'

  while(move_index > insert_index)
  {
    std::swap(v[move_index], v[move_index-1]);
    --move_index;
  }
  std::cout << v;
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3232e1991d389ad6). Note I used `std::string`, but the algorithm remains the same for `std::vector`. [The same can be done with iterators](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3d32feb2c745c9f), so you can generalize to containers that don't have `operator[]`.

Comment: The same can also be done with [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate), which has distance-between complexity. [See it live](https://ideone.com/1hZ4jc)

Comment: @WhozCraig yes indeed. I started writing this up with another result in mind, but indeed, your way would be more idiomatic, as I've just reimplemented `std::rotate`.

Answer (score 9):

I'd try with `std::rotate` first and only try other manual stuff (or a container other than vector) if that turns out not be efficient enough:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // move 5 from 4th to 1st index

    std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    // position:        0 1 2 3 4 5

    std::size_t i_old = 4;
    std::size_t i_new = 1;
    auto it = v.begin();

    std::rotate( it + i_new, it + i_old, it + i_old + 1);
    for (int i : v) std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bc42573c5e991ce).

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible to do this "efficiently" with `std::vector<>`, because it is stored in contiguous memory and you must therefore move everything between the old and new locations by one element.  So it's linear time in the length of the vector (or at least the distance moved).

The naive solution would be to `insert()` then `erase()`, but that requires moving everything after the rightmost location you modified, twice!  So instead you can do it "by hand", by copying `b` through `d` one position to the right (e.g. with `std::copy()`, then overwriting `b`.  At least then you avoid shifting anything outside the modified range.  It looks like you may be able to make `std::rotate()` do this, as @WhozCraig mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Thanks John, I thought about doing that but didn't pursue that as it feel like copying everything across by 1 would be inefficient...?

Comment: @JoshuaBatty you'd be surprised. depending on how large (more to the point: how *small*) a sequence you're talking about things can get pretty efficient inside that cache. A trivial example (uses an array rather than a vector simply because I was too lazy to type out the iterators =P) [can be found here](https://ideone.com/mIEFpu). Its an option, but for large  sequences, I'd likely go with a different data structure unless this is a *rare* operation. If it is rare and you spend most of your time *enumerating* that sequence linearly, a vector + rotate may still be warranted.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on jrok's answer, here's a wrapper around [`std::rotate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) for moving a single element around. This is more general than jrok's example, in that it supports moving an element forward in the vector too (rather than only backward).

See the comments within `rotate_single()` explaining how you have to swap the logic around when moving the element forward versus back.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept> // for std::domain_error in range-checking assertion
#include <algorithm> // for std::rotate()

template<class ContiguousContainer>
void assert_valid_idx(ContiguousContainer & v, size_t index)
{
    // You probably have a preferred assertion mechanism in your code base... 
    // This is just a sample.
    if(index >= v.size())
    {
        throw std::domain_error("Invalid index");
    }
}

template<class ContiguousContainer>
void rotate_single(ContiguousContainer & v, size_t from_index, size_t to_index)
{
    assert_valid_idx(v, from_index);
    assert_valid_idx(v, to_index);

    const auto from_it = v.begin() + from_index;
    const auto to_it   = v.begin() + to_index;
    if(from_index < to_index)
    {
        // We're rotating the element toward the back, so we want the new
        // front of our range to be the element just after the "from" iterator
        // (thereby making our "from" iterator the new end of the range).
        std::rotate(from_it, from_it + 1, to_it + 1);
    }
    else if(to_index < from_index)
    {
        // We're rotating the element toward the front, 
        // so we want the new front of the range to be the "from" iterator.
        std::rotate(to_it, from_it, from_it + 1);
    }
    // else the indices were equal, no rotate necessary
}
```

You can [play with this in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/YWad68)—there are (extensive) unit tests there, but here's an illustrative sample:

```
TEST_CASE("Handful of elements in the vector")
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; // Note: this gets recreated for each SECTION() below
    // position:       0  1  2  3  4  5
    
    SECTION("Interior moves")
    {
        SECTION("Move 5 from 4th to 1st index")
        {
            rotate_single(v, 4, 1);
            CHECK(v == std::vector<int>{1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6});
        }

        SECTION("Move 2 from 1st to 4th index")
        {
            rotate_single(v, 1, 4);
            CHECK(v == std::vector<int>{1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6});
        }
    }

    SECTION("Swap adjacent")
    {
        rotate_single(v, 4, 5);
        rotate_single(v, 0, 1);
        CHECK(v == std::vector<int>{2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5});
    }
}
```